# cakephp media plugin Fatal error: Call to undefined method Folder::ls()

Tags: php, cakephp, media

hi i am using cakephp media plugin and i got this error when i want to delete a file..

> cakephp media plugin Fatal error: Call to undefined method Folder::ls()

any help?

TIA :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the version of the media plugin you use is not compatible with the CakePHP version you use because `Folder::ls` has been removed in CakePHP 1.3.x. Hence I would check whether there is a newer version of the media plugin available.

Comment: i replaced the media plugin with the latest david persson's media plugin.. but still i can't delete a file.. but it has no error messages at all..